# What are they called: the kick stands and the defensive spike of a scooter / motorbike?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

A scooter / a motorbike often has **2** supporting structures to help itself to stand alone.

**1-** The 1st supporting structure could be a **V or U shape** steel one that helps the scooter / motorbike **stand up straight** without leaning aside. It seems like people call it "**kick stand**". See the 2 pictures below:

[image]

[image]

**2-** The 2nd supporting structure could be **a steel bar** that helps the the scooter / motorbike to stand by itself but not up straight. The scooter / motorbike may **lean a bit** to the side that has that steel bar. It seems like people call it "**defensive spike**".

[image]

[image]

What are they called: **the kick stands** and **the defensive spike** of a scooter / motorbike?

Or **do we have more general terms  for them?**

Comment: I used to call the stand that makes the machine stand upright the **centre stand**, and the single leg that is hinged, upon which the bike leans, the **prop stand** or **side stand**. These are British terms.

Comment: 2 - *It seems like people call it "defensive spike"*. No, it's called a **side stand** (UK) or **kickstand** (US). The term "Mad Max defensive spike" in the photo is a spoof name. Look at the other terms: "Pedestrian-seeking radar array", "10 kilowatt battery pack" etc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've kind of answered your own question. It doesn't matter what shape it is - if it is *fixed to the bike* and folded away by "kicking" it, then it is a **kickstand** (usually styled as a compound word, rather than as 'kick stand'.

A *removable* stand that goes in the middle of the bike used for maintenance is called a **centre stand**. This is not "kicked" away, but the bike is pulled up and onto it.

Comment: As a UK biker since the late 1960s I have heard kick stand, side stand and prop stand for the hinged one on the side that you extend with your foot.